# MySQL Workbench wont make constraint when parent table has Generated Virtual columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**SETUP**

MySQL Workbench (ver 6.3.9)

MySQL 5.7.21

My setup is simple.. I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `UserDevices` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UUID` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeviceName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeviceType` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `CreatedDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `TimeStamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `UserInfo` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UUID` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UUIDText` varchar(40) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (insert(insert(insert(insert(hex(`UUID`),9,0,'-'),14,0,'-'),19,0,'-'),24,0,'-')) VIRTUAL,
  `FirstName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FullName` varchar(90) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(`FirstName`,' ',`LastName`)) VIRTUAL,
  `Email` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` tinyint(3) DEFAULT '0',
  `AccountType` tinyint(3) DEFAULT '1',
  `CreatedDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `TimeStamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**PROBLEM**

When working inside Workbench I'm simply trying to Make a Foreign key constraint in table "UserDevices" on Column "UserID"  Pointed at Table "UserInfo" Column "ID".  When selecting "UserInfo" as the Referenced Table.  I can not put a check next to UserID.. Also no columns show up in the drop down list under Referenced Column..

**QUESTION**

I understand there are a number of reasons this scenario would happen.  But I'm not seeing Any data type mismatch or such that would explain this.  What is making it so I can't select UserID.ID?

P.S. Setting up another table named "DeviceMeasurements" with a Column "DeviceID" I'm completely successful at setting up the constraint exactly as expected.

**UPDATE**

On a hunch since this is my first time playing around with Generated Virtual Columns.  I went into the table and removed columns "UUIDText" and "FullName".  NOW I can build my constraints as desired.  But my question stands.  Why can't I build constraint with the tables built as above!?

**UPDATE 2**

This has been confirmed as a bug in WorkBench.  Manually adding the constraint via SQL code is a valid work around currently.  Please see accepted answer.

Comment: do you have more than one db? maybe you are accessing the wrong table? what happens when you create fk manually via sql code?

Comment: Yes, I have 7 different schemas in this one test box.  Wrong table selection has most definitely been ruled out.   Creating the constraint with sql code appears to be successful.  But that isn't currently the question/problem.

Comment: It may be an issue with mysql workbench, as opposed to an issue with mysql server. Have you tried creating the constraint manually?

Comment: @Shadow Yes, I am able to make the Constraints manually.  It appears that MySQL Work Bench falls on its face when the Parent table has Generated Virtual columns in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can confirm, this is a bug in WB. Have raised it with MySQL dev team.

[Bug link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90350)

Comment: If you could please clarify that one CAN in fact use SQL code to manually build the constraint for other users that come across this issue/answer.  Thanks for the confirmation.